# Chrome text-decoration line-through prevents click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I am programming a web app where clicking on a bit of text should toggle the `line-through` css style. This works on Firefox, but the `click` event seems not to fire in Chrome once the style has been applied.

HTML:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready({
        $(".liner").click(toggleStrikethrough);
    });
<div class="liner">
    Hello World
</div>
```

JS (note that I've used jQuery because that's what I'm using in the app, but a vanilla solution would be acceptable as well):

```
function toggleStrikethrough()
{
    if($(this).css("text-decoration") != "line-through")
        $(this).css("text-decoration","line-through");
    else
        $(this).css("text-decoration","");
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9027n6sb/15/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS3, `text-decoration` has multiple parts. In your particular case, the read `$(this).css("text-decoration")` returns `line-through solid rgb(0, 0, 0)`.

Instead, try changing the if condition to `$(this).css("text-decoration-line")` to get only the line style part of the text decoration.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve your problem using different way. I think it was succeeded. you can use below mention code to get same output that you want.

```js
  $('div').bind('click',function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('liner');
   });
```

```css
.liner{
    text-decoration:line-through;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery Exzmple</title>
    <style>

    </style>    
</head>
<body>
     <div class="liner">Hello World</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I used bind , toggleClass methods for this. As a result js code was simple and it could run efficiently.